# Under what conditions would converting from an integer to a string cause an exception?

Tags: vb.net, exception, type-conversion

I keep getting the following warning in my code. (Could be coming from ReSharper, I'm not certain.)

> Runtime errors might occur when converting 'Integer' to 'String'

Simple Repro:

```
Dim foo As Integer = 1
Dim bar As String
bar = 1
```

I just can't understand under what conditions this could possibly actually cause an exception. *Are they any?* Under what conditions would it be impossible to cast an Integer to String?

Comment: Set `OPTION STRICT` to `ON`. That's the most important improvement here. Then the question is obsolete because you need `bar=1.ToString()`

Comment: @TimSchmelter that ***is*** a goal here. It's legacy code and won't compile with `Option Strict` turned on quite yet.

Comment: Then make it compile, don't waste your time with fixing symptoms. Fix the root cause. However, you can use `bar=1.ToString()` to prevent the warning without changing `OPTION STRICT` if you can't do that.

Comment: @TimSchmelter. *Legacy*. No tests. Easier said than done cuz. I'm here in the real world where people inherit awful code with no tests that we can't afford to break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't cause a (runtime) exception.

It is warning you that you are not explicitly casting to a string.

You would actually get a compile time error if you have Option Strict On (which you should) but the error is different: `Option Strict disallows implicit conversions from Integer to String`. So I think this particular warning is coming from ReSharper.

In your case, you can switch Option Strict On, then change the Implicit Conversion Condition from Error to Warning until you have fixed them all.

Fixing this sort of thing is trivial:

```
Bar = CStr(1)
```

Which is the fix suggested by Visual Studio

Answer (score 1):

That specific code won't cause a runtime error*. It's a standard text that you get when you make an implicit conversion.

The main issue isn't that something might go wrong in the code, it's that the code is hiding what's actually happening. The integer value is implicitly converted into a string, without the code showing that.

In your example you are converting a literal number to a string, I think that you intended to convert the value in the variable `foo`, as it's there:

```
Dim foo As Integer = 1
Dim bar As String
bar = foo
```

To make the conversion explicit, just add a `ToString` call:

```
Dim foo As Integer = 1
Dim bar As String
bar = foo.ToString()
```

---

* For accuracy and completeness; theoreically a runtime could happen, in the extreme situation where you run out of memory so that it's not possible to create another string. It's not a situation that you normally consider whenever the code creates a string.